# stop and later persue javascript event in jquery ui modal dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, events, modal-dialog

I want to stop an event show a modal dialog and if the user presses yes persue this event. event.run() brings an error in firefox.

```
jQuery(element).click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    dialog.dialog({
        buttons: {
            'Ja': function() {
                event.run();
            },
            'Nein': function() {
                jQuery(this).dialog('close');
            }

        }
    }).dialog('open');
});
```

Thanks to a friend and hashbrown I managed to solve this problem. An event cannot be paused and persued. If it is paused it will block the whole DOM. Try:

```
jQuery(link).click(function(){while(true)});
```

When using jQuery its possible to set additional event parameters what I did:

```
jQuery(element).click(function(event, show_dialog) {
    var that = jQuery(this);
    if(!show_dialog) {
        dialog.dialog({
            buttons: {
                'Yes': function() {
                    that.trigger(event.type, [true]);
                },
                'No': function() {
                    jQuery(this).dialog('close');
                }

            }
        }).dialog('open');
        return false;
    } else {
        dialog.dialog('close');
        return true;
    }
});
```

First click show_dialog is undefined and modal dialog is shown. Clicking on Yes in modal dialog triggers the event.type (click) with the additional parameter true for show_dialog. http://api.jquery.com/trigger/#trigger-eventType-extraParameters

It was not possible to `that.trigger(event, [true]);`. I think cause events default action was prevented before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because immediately after creating the popup the function returns and the event expires.
[What you'll have to do](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) is `.trigger()` a new event.

Note: set some sort of global variable to ignore this second event firing in your anonymous function (infinite loop problem).

Can I ask why you want to do this; what would `click` go off and do if you let it?
If it just fires off a different function, why not just call that function instead of attempting `event.run()`?

Comment: I want to bind this dialog to some elements where I don't know which other functions were bind to. I now have a solution with the trigger function.